# Unexpected resultset using different methods that should produce the same output

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

Using a PDO class with Mysqli I get unexpected results. Check this comparison that should produce the same results imho.

`$versions` is an array containing elements 8, 9 or both.
In both examples below, the array is:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 9
        [1] => 8
    )
```

---

Using this (more correctly) PDO method:

```
function getQuestions($nrOfQuestions = 25, $versions){
    $versions = implode(",", $versions);
    $args= array(
            "nrOfQ" => $nrOfQuestions
            ,"versions" => $versions
    );
    return $db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . TABLE . "` WHERE `version` IN (:versions) && `qc` >= 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT :nrOfQ", $args);
}
```

**Unexpected Result:**
all results are version 9 (I expect 8 aswel here)

---

Using this (dirty?) concatenation method:

```
function getQuestions($nrOfQuestions = 25, $versions){
    $versions = implode(",", $versions);
    $args= array(
            "nrOfQ" => $nrOfQuestions
    );
    return $db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . TABLE . "` WHERE `version` IN (" . $versions . ") && `qc` >= 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT :nrOfQ", $args);
}
```

**Result is as expected**
: Results are randomly version 8 and 9 as expected.

---

My question is:
Why the difference here in the resultset?
The IN clause in the query should be `(9,8)` in both cases but produce different results.

Comment: @Juakali92 indeed! I'll stick to the 'dirty' solution then.

Comment: sometimes the dirty solution is the only solution.

Comment: The `:versions` shouldn't work. It creates a CSV string which wouldn't match. e.g. it is bound as `'8 ,9'` as 1 value, not 2.